# Nhibernate and indexed view

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have an `Album` entity which has `IList<Photo>` in it. I want to select all my albums with count of photos with one fast query using NHibernate. Before migrating to NH I had a query using an indexed view:

```
SELECT a.*, t.PhotoCount
FROM dbo.Album a
LEFT JOIN dbo.vw_AlbumPhotoCount t ON t.AlbumID = a.AlbumID
```

How can I use this view (`vw_AlbumPhotoCount`) in NHibernate to speed up the query?

**UPDATE:**
I mapped a simple `<one-to-one/>` entity as Alex advised and it worked for me. One downside of this solution - as `one-to-one` properties cannot be loaded lazily I always get `LEFT JOIN` when fetching album by id. I couldn't map this entity as `<many-to-one/>` property, I'm not sure why maybe because the view doesn't have its own ID property. Anyway ofter mapping it as `<many-to-one/>` I got null in it after fetching an album

**UPDATE 2:**
I've reviewed my architecture and decided to remove the view. The best way in this particular situation is using NH caching system instead of indexed view

Comment: Your best bet may be to map a simple entity to your PhotoCount view, and then set up a relationship that way.  Just make sure you don't cache these objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet may be to map a simple entity to your PhotoCount view, and then set up a relationship to that entity through ordinary means. Just make sure you don't cache these objects, because they will never actually get updated.

Answer (score 0):

a Property on the Album with a formula

```
// Fluent Mapping
Map(x => x.PhotoCount).Formula("SELECT t.PhotoCount FROM dbo.vw_AlbumPhotoCount t ON t.AlbumID = AlbumID");

// xml mapping
<property name="PhotoCount" formula="SELECT t.PhotoCount FROM dbo.vw_AlbumPhotoCount t ON t.AlbumID = AlbumID">

var albums = session.QueryOver<Album>().List();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but what about selecting list of albums?